How to force Itext 7 PDF to NOT trim whitespaces?
I want to create a PDF that has this kind of layout:
1.  Name  : John Doe
    Class : I-A
    Grade : 100
    Status: PASS

I use this code to generate the PDF:
    public void generateDoc(List<String> toPrint) throws IOException {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(path);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        document.setFontSize(10.0F);
        document.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER));
        document.setMargins(10F, 0F, 10F, 0F);
        for(String s : toPrint) {
            if(s.equals("EOF")) document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
            else document.add(new Paragraph(s));
        }
        document.close();
    }

The toPrint list contains formatted string towards desired output as I use Courier font, which has monospace feature:
[
 "1.  Name  : John Doe",
 "    Class : I-A",
 "    Grade : 100",
 "    Status: PASS"
]

Then the result PDF file turns out to be like this:
1.  Name  : John Doe
Class : I-A
Grade : 100
Status: PASS

Is there anyway to make this work as I have formatted List of Strings?

Instead of using regular space  , use the non breaking space character (\u00a0)  instead in the formatted Strings.
Or, replace the spaces will also do:
document.add(new Paragraph(s.replaceAll(" ", "\u00a0")));


Actually just replacing the first space character will do.

Prepending all line with a zero width space ("​\u200B​") ​​​​​​ also helps. and can easily be done in the process.
